# Solr error on adding patch for fallback language

Tags: solr, language-fallback

I am  using  Sitecore 10.2 with SXA.
I have added a patch file for fallback language in solr. When I deploy this patch file,on CM server it works fine but on CD server I get the error. **Could not find method: AddIndex.(Screenshot attached).**

Please suggest what could be missing.
Patch file code:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">

    <sitecore search:require="solr">
        <contentSearch>
            <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <indexes>
                    <index id="sitecore_master_index">
                        <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
                        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
                    </index>
                    <index id="sitecore_web_index">
                        <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
                        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
                    </index>
                </indexes>
            </configuration>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you are trying to patch `master` database/index when it is not present on CD instance?

Comment: Indeed I missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CD server should not have access to `master` index and no configurations for it. To fix this issue you can add `role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement"` to your `master` index  as below:

```
<sitecore search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
        <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <indexes>
                <index id="sitecore_master_index" role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" >
                    <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
                    <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_web_index">
                    <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
                    <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
                </index>
            </indexes>
        </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Indeed I missed that. Thanks :)